# How can I change the text of a label in a button event?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Just doing my very first test app with Xamarin.
How can I change (within a button event) the text in the label from "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" to "Hello World" ?

I tried to do so with the following XAML script and C# code:

XAMLscript within the Stacklayout and my C# code in mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="click here" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label.Text = "Hello World";
    }
```

Somehow the system does not accept .Text as a property of the label.

Answer (score 1):

I already found the error myself. Here is the correct code after having added x:Name:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="myLabel"/>
    <Button Text="click here" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />


private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.Text = "Hello World";
    }
```

Comment: After two days, please do not forget to mark you answer, it will help others who have similar issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are super close! You have to give a name property to your label, it's like a variable name.

```
<Label x:Name="label"..../>
```

and then in your function, you can just say

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        label.Text = "Changed";
}
```